# sequence of function either in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, geometry

I need help with the sequence of functions that I have here (specifically, the order of `initialize()` and `calculation()`) which are coded as
follows:

**initialize:**

```
function initialize()
    {

    <?php if (isset($y) && isset($x)){ ?>
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.510, 74.300); <?php } 
        else 
        { ?>
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.510, 74.300)
        <?php 
        } ?>
        var mapProp = 
        {
            center:center,
            zoom:7,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("pagePro"),mapProp);



    }
```

**calculation:**

```
 function calculation(){
     // Get coordinates of route and display it
        for(m=1;m<=2;m++){

            //alert(m);
        $.ajax({
        url: "route_query4district.php?id="+m,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg1) 
        { 
        xarray1 = new Array();
         yarray1 = new Array();
         color1 = new Array();
         new_id = new Array();
         dist_name = new Array();
        js_data1 = eval(msg1);
            //alert(js_data1);
            var k1=0;
            for(j1=0;j1<js_data1.length;j1+=5){
            xarray1[k1] = js_data1[j1];
            yarray1[k1] = js_data1[j1+1];
            color1[k1] = js_data1[j1+2];
            new_id[0] = js_data1[j1+3];
            dist_name[0] = js_data1[j1+4];
            k1++;
            }
        //alert(dist_name);
            var flightPlanCoordinates = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<xarray1.length;i++){
             flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(yarray1[i], xarray1[i]);
            }


        };
```

Is this possible in javascript or jquery?

Comment: `initialize(); calculation();` ?

Comment: this method is not working

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: calculation(); not read by browser.while if I place #calculation(); in 1st one function than both codes are working well but 2nd one run first which must run after Initialize(); function